# Total/Average/Changing Salary 1,2,3,4 Menu

Tags: python, python-3.3

Change your program so there is a main menu for the manager to select from with four options:

1. Print the total weekly salaries bill.
2. Print the average salary.
3. Change a player’s salary.
4. Quit

When I run the program, I enter the number 1 and the program stops. How do I link it to the 4 below programs?

**Program:**

```
Chelsea_Salaries_2014 = {'Jose Mourinho':[53, 163500, 'Unknown']}
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Eden Hazard']=[22, 185000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Fernando Torres']=[29, 175000, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['John Terry']=[32, 175000, 'June 2015']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Frank Lampard']=[35, 125000, 'June 2014']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ashley Cole']=[32, 120000, 'June 2014']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Petr Cech']=[31, 100000, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Gary Cahill']=[27, 80000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['David Luiz']=[26, 75000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['John Obi Mikel']=[26, 75000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Nemanja Matic']=[25, 75000, 'June 2019']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Marco Van Ginkel']=[20, 30000, 'June 2018']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ramires']=[26, 60000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Oscar']=[21, 67500, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Lucas Piazon']=[19, 15000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ryan Bertrand']=[23, 35000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Marko Marin']=[27, 35000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Cesar Azpilicueta']=[23, 55000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Branislav Ivanovic']=[29, 67500, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ross Turnbull']=[22, 17000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Demba Ba']=[28, 65000, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Oriol Romeu']=[22, 15000, 'June 2015']

user_input = (int('Welcome! What would you like to do? 1: Print the total salaries bill. 2: Print the average salary. 3: Change a players salary. 4: Quit. '))

if user_input == 1:
    print(sum(i[1] for i in Chelsea_Salaries_2014.values()))
else:
    if user_input == 2:
       print(sum(i[1] for i in Chelsea_Salaries_2014.values()))/len(Chelsea_Salaries_2014)
    else:
        if user_input == 3:
            def change_salary(Chelsea_Salaries_2014):
                search_input = input('What player would you like to search for? ')
                print('His Current Salary is £{0:,}'.format(Chelsea_Salaries_2014[search_input][1]))
                new_salary = int(input('What would you like to change his salary to? '))
            if new_salary <= 200000:
                Chelsea_Salaries_2014[search_input][1] = new_salary
                print('Salary has been changed to £{0:,}'.format(new_salary))
            else:
                print('This salary is ridiculous!')

            while True:
                change_salary(Chelsea_Salaries_2014)
                choice = input("Go again? y/n ")
                if choice.lower() in ('n', 'no'):
                        break
        else:
            if user_input == 4:
                print('Goodbye!')
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: your indentation is broken and you've got a function definition in the middle of your code.

Comment: You copy and pasted your homework/test question.

Comment: @BillGregg: No I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Put the raw input in a while.

```
 while True:
 user_input = raw_input("Welcome!...")
 if user_input == 1:
  ...
 elif user_unput == 2:
  ...
 else:
  print "this salary is ridic..."
```

After completing a 1,2,3... input ask the user if they would like to do something else y/n, if n: break, this will end the loop. If y, the loop begins again and asks for another user input.

Comment: Kudos to you for being able to answer a non existing question ;-))

Comment: Don't use a flag. Just use `while True:` and `break` out of the loop.